# Press a button to Insert text into html from client.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I use a php to create a guest message board so user can leave message.

I didn't use any database, it is just a text file and append new data.

Is there any easy way to use something like jQuery for user to add new content into the message he left before?

To be clear, I don't want to use any database. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: jQuery - append. but seems not persistent. I need to actually update that file.

Comment: jQuery runs on the CLIENT, your message board file is on the SERVER.  You need to update the file using a server side PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the file with a good structure so the information is easily parseable.
2. Open file with PHP and parse the information into an object.
3. Export the object with for example json_encode trough an api
4. Fetch the object with jQuery
5. When someone adds a message send it trough jQuery to back-end where you append the message to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Since javascript/jquery is a client language while PHP runs on server. You can use jQuery ajax to send text in a saperate php file via query string where you can append text using PHP fwrite function. here is an idea example to make clear:

**jQuery:**

`var textfield = $('textarea'); //your text area field`

`var pathToPHP = "Your path to php script/text.php?text="+textfield;`

//get text via query string

`$.ajax({ URL:pathToPHP , method:"GET", cache:false, type:"HTML" });`

//Send text to PHP script using Ajax

You can find further ajax options via [jQuery ajax API](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax)

**PHP:**

`$text = $_GET['text'];            //Get the Text
$txt_file_path = "file.txt";        //Path to text file
$read = fopen($txt_file_path,"w");  //Open Text file in write mode
$new_content = $read." ".$text;     //Old Content + New Content
fwrite($read,$new_content);         //Rewrite Text file
fclose($read);             //Close file`

This php code is just for idea and you can refer to [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [fwrite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) for complete solution